# VScode terminal does not have conda terminal in windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda

I seldom program in windows these days. In Linux, I use vscode and their terminal same as I use the ubuntu terminal. No problem there with conda, git etc.

However in windows when I use vscode the terminal attached is either:

- powershell
- Git bash
- Command

I just found out there is git bash and that is a relief, but I can not do conda in the powershell or the command because "conda is not recognized"

So I have to use the anaconda terminal to use conda.

Is there a way that I can add a terminal where I can use conda in vscode windows?